# Running Selenium on WSL using Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, selenium

I want to use Capybara to run some automated tests with Chrome, how do I choose to run the google-chrome-dev instead of the default Chrome? Only Chrome 78 (unstable) will run, however, Selenium (for Capybara) requires webdriver. Webdriver only support version 77.

I was able to get Chrome running by following these instructions:
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/648#issuecomment-324562271

WSL Capybara and the WSL Chrome Window:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

> How do I choose to run the google-chrome-dev instead of the default Chrome?

### Links:

Choose any one of the following links:

- Stable: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
- Beta: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-beta_current_amd64.deb
- Dev: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb

The version and release timeline can be viewed here [Chrome Status Schedule](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule/).

### Steps:

- Add `apt` installation key ([source](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)):

  ```
  wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
  ```
- Download the package:

  ```
  wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-beta_current_amd64.deb
  ```
- Try to install the package:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-beta_current_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install the dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt -f install
  ```
- Now install the actual package:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-beta_current_amd64.deb
  ```

Comment: where do i find the path to installation?

Comment: @Alvaro `which google-chrome` shows `/usr/bin/google-chrome` but it is a symbolic link.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have not yet found the solution (WSL2). Follow this tutorial: [chromedriver in WSL2](https://www.gregbrisebois.com/posts/chromedriver-in-wsl2/).
Many are similar, but what did the trick for me was to place the chromedriver in the corresponding group and user:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't try to answer old questions and please expand your answer.